# NSRulerView, Extending Vertical Measures to the Bottom

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

I've hacked Apple's sample project called **Rulers** to create a simple **NSView** subclass in order to show vertical and horizontal rulers.  It looks like the following.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    NSScrollView *scrollView = [self enclosingScrollView];
    if (!scrollView) return;
    [scrollView setHasHorizontalRuler:YES];
    [scrollView setHasVerticalRuler:YES];
    [self setRulerOffsets];
    [self updateRulers];
    [scrollView setRulersVisible:YES];
    return;
}

+ (void)initialize {
    NSArray *upArray;
    NSArray *downArray;
    upArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:2.0], nil];
    downArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.5],[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.2],nil];
    [NSRulerView registerUnitWithName:@"Grummets" abbreviation:NSLocalizedString(@"gt",@"Grummets abbreviation string") unitToPointsConversionFactor:100.0 stepUpCycle:upArray stepDownCycle:downArray];
    return;
}

- (void)setRulerOffsets {
    NSScrollView *scrollView = [self enclosingScrollView];
    NSRulerView *horizRuler;
    NSRulerView *vertRuler;
    NSView *docView;
    NSView *clientView;
    NSPoint zero;
    docView = [scrollView documentView];
    clientView = self;
    ...
}
```

The picture below is what I have.

[image]

My question is whether or not it's possible to reverse the vertical measurements.  For now, 0 lies at the bottom.  Is it possible to set the start at the top and then extend it down to the bottom?

Thanks.

Comment: change the value of "flipped" for the rulers

Comment: hehehe...  I didn't think about that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> A vertical ruler takes into account whether the coordinate system of the NSScrollView’s document view—not the receiver’s client view—is flipped. A horizontal ruler is always flipped.

So you might be able to fix this by having your document view's coordinate system be flipped (you can override `isFlipped` on the view).

Best of luck — this API is [over 15 years old](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/#OpenStepNotes) :)

Comment: ..that's how we're using it and it works just fine. Well, mostly. We're doing our own drawing, though - the style looks like the original Next-Step widget